# iOS: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:] synchronicity and error handling

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I would like to know if there is anyway to receive a status or callback from an iOS system app after being launched via a URL from your app, for example:

User opens my application-->clicks on a FaceTime URL
FaceTime is opened and begins ringing-->FaceTime call times out 
Call ended-->FaceTime relays to my application that this call was not successful

The Apple developer docs provide a very helpful [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1%22article%22) detailing how to blindly fire these apps, but no way to actually act upon whatever happened after the fact.

If this isn't possible, no worries, but I figure there should be some delegates / event handlers in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if the app you are calling is written specifically to "call your app back". In general, few apps support this.

One standard for this is [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com/).

A [search on Stack Overflow for "x-callback"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%5bios%5d%20x-callback) shows some relevant information.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually very helpful. I suppose the proper question then is if FaceTime or any other apple system apps support the x-callback-url scheme?

Comment: Apple would document such a thing if they did. The [FaceTime Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH2-SW1) page doesn't mention anything.

Comment: I figured as much, but wanted to hold onto some hope that there would be a smart way to handle such things. Maybe somewhere down the line, who knows? Thanks again. I'll keep a lookout for x-callback-url supported apps.